# Error message every time I try to launch Mac OS classic

Tags: mac-os-classic, imac-g3, imac, power-macintosh

I'm on an iMac G3 running OS 10.3 - trying to launch OS classic 9.2. Every time I try to launch it, regardless of if I have extensions turned on or off, I get the error message:

**The volume for "Serial Port Monitor" cannot be found.**

*Insert the volume for "Serial Port Monitor" and wait for it to appear on the desktop, then try again.*

I don't know what this means or how to fix! I am very new to retro computing. I have no internet connection to download a software update but I am able to install new software and add files via USB transfer.

Comment: You're restarting, or just trying to launch the Classic Environment? Have you tried holding shift to disable extensions?

Comment: Is this about the term 'Volume'? That's what Mac calls a drive, real or virtual. So this may be due some reference pointing to a volume holding, that extension, present when that image was generated but not now.

Comment: Noting for completeness that this question [was also asked on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/VintageApple/comments/14jhzi8/error_message_every_time_i_try_to_launch_classic/) where it looks like the problem is not yet completely resolved, but it'd probably be helpful to transcribe the outcome once known into a community wiki answer.

Comment: What happens if you dismiss the dialog, either via OK button (if it has one), or Command-period?

Comment: @Tommy ahh that reddit post was mine too hehe - temporarily fixed it by deleting serial port monitor files. now I can launch classic apps like installers and retro games and such but I cant launch the classic desktop, so not a complete fix. shame cuz now when I launch classic it just crashes and returns me to desktop without any error message so idk what to do

Comment: @supercat dismissing it didn't do anything, it would crash every time and display that error

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue has already been fixed - if you read the Reddit thread. OP should post the answer and mark answer as accepted.